# SharePoint 2016 - Is it possible to have Calendar events color-coded based on conditional formatting? Not Calendar layers for different categories

Tags: 2016, list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, xslt-list-view-web-part

So Google showed me how to set up different Calendar overlays and how to assign a color to events based on their categories, but I am looking for something different.

Is there any kind of code that would allow me to set conditional formatting rules so that calendar event colors can change? Specifically, I would like for calendar events to turn red when the event time has elapsed to signal that a task has not yet been completed. For users to prevent this and show that they have completed the calendar event task, they would  edit a calendar event's category or something to being "Completed" which I would want to set a conditional formatting rule to not have "Completed" events turn red beyond their scheduled date/time and maybe have "Completed" events turn green.

When I go to create a new view for a Calendar, I see an option that reads "Custom View in SharePoint Designer: Start SharePoint Designer to create a new view for this list such as conditional formatting."  I have no clue how to set up conditional in formatting in Designer though and I am not even sure if what I want to do is possible. I couldnt find any info on Google about this either.  Any help or code examples would be great appreciated!